# Firebase Cloud Messaging with ionic Chat App

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am developing android/ios chat app using ionic framework  and I want to add Push Notification with the help of new firebase feature FCM. simple push notification working fine using this plugin https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm but now i want to send message to another device how is it works in app. when i write FCMPlugin in App.js face many errors.

Controller.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'FCMPlugin', 'intlpnIonic', 'ionic-material', 'ngStorage', 'ngCordovaOauth', 'firebase', 'ngCordova'])
```

Error

```
  ionic.bundle.js:13438 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module FCMPlugin due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'FCMPlugin' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=FCMPlugin
    at http://192.168.15.34:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13438:12
    at http://192.168.15.34:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15404:17
    at ensure
```

Comment: Can you reformat your question first? Then can you load the full stacktrace? It looks like you are trying to inject a module into FCMPlugin. That module may not have been initialized

Comment: @Mukus now see this

Comment: You can use firebase realtime database for chat application using chat room concept